# How to substitute all occurrences after a certain number with sed in OS X

Tags: macos, bash, sed, osx-yosemite

I am trying to modify a bad `.csv` file, where the last 'column' is broken into a different number of columns due to extra `,` characters. I want to use `sed` to keep the first 4 commas, and replace the rest with `;`. The following seems not to work on OS X:

```
sed 's/,/;/4g' file
```

Is there an alternative to this in OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an OSX box to test with, but try this:

```
sed -E '
    s/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/\1\x1f\2\x1f\3\x1f\4/
    s/,/;/g
    s/\x1f/,/g
' file
```

That transforms the first 3 commas into the ascii "unit separator" control character, translates all the rest of the commas into semicolons, then translates the control characters back into commas.

Demo:

```
$ echo "a,b,c,d,e,f" | sed -E 's/^([^,]*),([^,]*),([^,]*),(.*)/\1\x1f\2\x1f\3\x1f\4/; s/,/;/g; s/\x1f/,/g'
a,b,c,d;e;f
```